# Puppeteer - Page.evaluate using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs, puppeteer

I am trying to use `"puppeteer": "^1.16.0",` and `"moment": "^2.24.0",`. When running `page.evaluate()` to convert a string to a date obj via moment I get:

> Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: moment is not defined

Find below my minimum example:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra")
const moment = require('moment')

function shuffle(dataObjArr) {
    let res = dataObjArr.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    return res
}

let issuerUrls = JSON.parse('[{"id":62,"name":"Product 1","ecomUrl":"/product/252","createdAt":"2019-05-25T07:51:49.000Z","updatedAt":"2019-05-25T07:51:49.000Z"},  {"id":15,"name":"Product 2","ecomUrl":"/product/251","createdAt":"2019-05-25T07:51:49.000Z","updatedAt":"2019-05-25T07:51:49.000Z"}]')

let issuerUrlsShuffled = shuffle(issuerUrls)
let BASE_URL = "https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone"
// puppeteer usage as normal
puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--disable-notifications"]
}).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    })

    for (let i = 0; i < issuerUrlsShuffled.length; i++) {
        try {

            let URL = BASE_URL + issuerUrlsShuffled[i].ecomUrl;

            await page.goto(URL)

            page.waitForNavigation({
                timeout: 60,
                waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
            });

            const data = await page.evaluate(() => {

                const priceData = []

                let date = "9/23/2016" // this is needed for testing purposes only!!!

                priceData.push({
                    price_date: moment(date, 'M/DD/YYYY').toDate()
                })
                return priceData
            }, moment)

            // show data
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))

            await page.waitFor(3000)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    await browser.close()
})
```

As you can see I tried to pass the `moment` instance to the `evaluate` function, however I still get the error.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only pass serializable data to the `page.evaluate` function as argument. (see the [docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) for more information). As `moment` is a function and a function cannot be serialized you cannot use it that easy.

To expose a function to the page from your Node.js environment, you can use the [`page.exposeFunction`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction). Quote from the docs:

> The method adds a function called `name` on the page's `window` object. When called, the function executes `puppeteerFunction` in node.js and returns a Promise which resolves to the return value of `puppeteerFunction`.

**Code sample:**

The following code inside your Node.js environment sets up a function `formatDate` which returns the formatted date:

```js
await page.exposeFunction('formatDate', (date) =>
  moment(date, 'M/DD/YYYY').toDate()
);
```

Be aware that you only need to call `exposeFunction` once on the page as it survives navigation. That means you can put this code outside of the loop.

Then your puppeteer code could use the function like this:

```js
const data = await page.evaluate(async () => {
  const priceData = []
  let date = "9/23/2016"
  priceData.push({
    price_date: await window.formatDate(date)
  })
  return priceData
})
```

Comment: @Vaviloff Thanks for the hint. :) The `await` was missing... Just tried it myself and it works now.

Comment: Thx the code works. However, when the script ends I get the following error: `Error: Failed to add page binding with name formatDate: window['formatDate'] already exists!` Any suggestions why?

Comment: @Anna.Klee I guess you put the function inside the loop? You should only bind the function to the page once and not after every page navigation. Therefore, you can put it outside of the loop and the error should be gone.

Comment: :D Nice to see Thomas and Vaviloff and everyone helping each other. I think we should note on the answer, The expose function should be added before any kind of loop or navigation, since "Functions installed via page.exposeFunction survive navigations."

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher The puppeteer-stackoverflow squad coming together :D Added the hint to the answer.